# Get text from one page and pass into another page using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I am new to selenium C# and i am having challenge in fetching a text from one method and passing the value into another method.

I have integrated spec flow in my project. So i have created test methods and
calling them.
The challenge is i have two URLs so i need to navigate to first URL, do some actions in those pages, get the text from one of the screens in URL 1 ( which i have achieved) and then switch to  URL 2, Do some action and  pass the text value of the web element into a field in the page.

Can anyone please help me how to achieve this?

Comment: can you add the code that you have tried so far and where exactly you are having difficulty?

Comment: post your code please ,

Comment: Method1: 
   public string findUserFromURL1()
        {
            IWebElement user_id = selenium.driver.FindElement(By.Id("user"));
            String a = user_id.Text;
            Console.WriteLine("user_id :" + a);
            return b;
        }


    Method 2:
 public void SearchUserFromUrl2() 
          {
             
          selenium.driver.FindElement(UserTab).Click();
              selenium.driver.FindElement(By.Id(user).SendKeys( I NEED TO PASS THE USER ID TEXT HERE);
            

          }

Comment: You can use specflow dictionary. `FeatureContext.Current["user"] = "user_id";` you can get that user id in the second method `var userId = FeatureContext.Current["user"];`